# Difficulties defining relationship for archived data

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In short; we need a cache, that cache has related entities. We also need to then store the expired items in a separate table for compliance and archival reasons.

Imagine the following four classes:

```
public abstract class Cache
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Cache() 
    {
        Entities = new HashSet<Entity>();
    }
    public ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class AvailableCache : Cache
{

}

public class ArchivedCache : Cache
{

}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CacheId { get; set; }
    public AvailableCache { get; set; }
    public ArchivedCache { get; set; }
}
```

Together with the following **DbContext**:

```
public partial class DbCacheContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<AvailableCache> { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArchivedCache> { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreatning(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedCache>(p => 
        {
            p.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            p.HasMany(p => p.Entities).WithOne(p => p.ArchivedCache).HasForeignKey(p => p.CacheId);
        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableCache>(p => 
        {
            p.HasMany(p => p.Entites).WithOne(p => p.AvailableCache).HasForeignkey(p => p.CacheId);
        }
}
```

A recurring job populates the cache, checks for expired items and archives them. First attempt a column was added to ArchivedCache

```
public class ArchivedCache : Cache
{
    public int OriginalId { get; set; }
}
```

This was then used as to save the original ID to define the relationship toward Entity. Then I tried to remove that, adding the ValueGeneratedOnAdd() and give it the same ID as AvailableCache.

The issue is that when trying to insert an Entity the foreign key constraint won't allow it since it doesn't exist in that table.

Since AvailableCache and ArchivedCache basically same object I would like to keep the relationship simple toward Entity.

Currently as I see it I have three options, I don't like any of them:

1. Define both IDs on Entity (I don't like this option because I don't want to clutter Entity with two ID:s that in the end point toward the same object, just in different tables/times)
2. Skip the ArchivedCache relationship and let the DBA worry about it since he was the one that specifically requested this.
3. I could remove the abstract class, resulting in one table with a discriminator but the DBA insisted on two tables.

But before I do either I wanted to check if there's perhaps something in EF Core that would allow this.

Comment: Cache object aren't exactly *entities*. If the question was about normal entities I'd say that the entities aren't different so the application shouldn't even know where they are stored. Their storage should be handled by the database. SQL Server has ways of making this transparent, either with table partitions in previous versions or temporal tables since 2016. Partitions are available in all editions, even Express, since 2016 too.

Comment: Even without these, the entity could be mapped to a *view* that UNIONs the two tables. Moving records around should be a stored procedure's job. The view will be editable if written properly.

Comment: I'll check it out but the recurring job that populates the cache from numerous sources and then determines what has expires runs in the same application, using the same DbContext.

Comment: The right tool for the right job. ORMs are meant to make writing OO applications easier, they aren't a replacement for SQL. In any case, if the two tables have eg an `IsActive` field with CHECK constraints that only allow eg 1 in the active table, 0 in the inactive one, the server itself will pick the correct table when inserting. BUT ...

Comment: That's all if you asked about *entities*. You asked about *caching* though, which is a different, purely techincal concern, doesn't really need history or auditing, has eviction and expiration policies. The two terms are *very* different. If the *DBA* asked for *Auditing*, you probably arent' dealing with caching at all. The DBA's request is based on a *domain* requirement that probably needs to be reflected in the application's model as well

Comment: Believe me, _I know_, but the DBA insisted on killing two birds with one stone. My arguments of IoC-concerns, cache-definition and technical implementation issues fell on deaf ears and now I'm just following orders.